# Integração do JSON com Swift

Tags: json, swift

Queria saber como eu faço para passar um JSON com a minha URL para Swift.

Eu tenho um como exemplo: http://peps.com.br/pips/teste2.json e se alguém puder fazer o começo da minha JSON na linguagem Swift já me ajudaria bastante pois não estou conseguindo sair do lugar.

---

então , na minha empresa a gente tem que integrar um JSON que eu passei o link na pergunta pra vocês verem e que faca aparecer no compilador do XCODE com a linguagem SWIFT as informações desta JSON , mas ta complicado , eu queria que pelo menos alguem fizesse a primeira parte disso para eu dar continuidade , pois ainda não me abriu a cabeça amplamente como integrar isso !

Comment: Rafael, você pode acrescentar mais detalhes? Como assim "fazer JSON em Swift"? Você quer gerar ou interpretar o JSON? Poderia [edit] e complementar a pergunta por favor? N!ão sei nada de swift, mas talvez para interpretar dê até para usar a tipagem fraca da linguagem, e simplesmente guardar o JSON numa variável. Ver http://owensd.io/2014/06/21/json-parsing-take-two.html

Answer (score 2):

Outra solução:

Tente isso no seu Playground do `Xcode 6.1.1`. No Playground é rapido de testar, depois você migra pro seu projeto.

```
import Foundation
let jsonObject: [AnyObject] = [
  ["name": "João", "age": 20],
  ["name": "Pedro", "age": 45],
]
func JSONStringify(jsonObj: AnyObject) -> String {
  var e: NSError?
  let jsonData: NSData! = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(
    jsonObj,
    options: NSJSONWritingOptions(0),
    error: &e)
  if e != nil {
    return ""
  } else {
    return NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
  }
}
let jsonString = JSONStringify(jsonObject)
println(jsonString)
```

Funciona no **Mavericks** e no **Yosemite**

Desta forma funciona pois você está delegando o trabalho de serialização à [classe `NSJSONSerialization` da biblioteca padrão](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html)

Ou seja, seu código Swift é apenas um Wrapper.

A deserialização também pode ser feita de forma análoga.

Answer (score 0):

Rafael, em um de nossos projetos, que eh uma app bem complexa, utilizamos o [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). Sua utilizacao eh tao simples quanto

```
let json = JSON(data: dataFromNetworking)
```

Depois voce vai pegando os valores por *subscript*:

```
let userId = json["compromissos"][0]["usuario_id"].intValue
let userName = json["compromissos"][0]["usuario_nome"].stringValue
```

Isso de modo bem simplificado, porque voce provalmente vai utilizar arrays:

```
let appointments = json["compromissos"].arrayValue
```

Para fazer os `requests` utilizamos o `AFNetworking`, mas voce pode utilizar o Alamofire conforme esta na pagina do SwitfyJSON.

Answer (score 0):

Rafael, tentei criar um exemplo para tentar sanar sua dúvida utilizando outra possibilidade o Codable, esse json representa um objeto que queremos utilizar no nosso projeto, na segunda imagem é como representaremos o objeto no código. Utilizando o Encodable, é possível você criar um json a partir de um objeto Swift e o Decodable é utilizado para você converter o json em um objeto no Swift. Para finalizar, como sua tarefa é apenas a realização da decodificação você deve pegar o Data obtido na sua requisição e tentar converte-lô para sua struct.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso continue com dúvidas, esse é o link da documentação oficial -https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types